# Как мне поменять цвет фона всплывающей панели на прозрачный?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, диаграммы

Я использую библиотеку для построения графиков [APEXCHART](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options)
Единственное, что не  могу найти в документации - это как изменить цвет этой панели на другой.
Помогите ребят разобраться)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код компонента:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="chart">
      <h2 class="text-lg text-center font-semibold" v-if="title">
        {{ title }}
      </h2>

      <apexchart
        type="line"
        height="350"
        :options="chartOptions"
        :series="series"
        ref="chart"
      ></apexchart>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueApexCharts from "vue3-apexcharts";
export default {
  components: {
    apexchart: VueApexCharts,
  },
  props: {
    dataset: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {},
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      series: [],
      chartOptions: {
        tooltip: {
          enabled: true,
          enabledOnSeries: undefined,
          shared: true,
          followCursor: false,
          intersect: false,
          inverseOrder: false,
          custom: undefined,
          fillSeriesColor: false,
          theme: false,
          style: {
            fontSize: "12px",
            fontFamily: undefined,
          },
          onDatasetHover: {
            highlightDataSeries: false,
          },
          x: {
            show: true,
            format: "dd MMM",
            formatter: undefined,
          },
          y: {
            formatter: undefined,
            title: {
              formatter: (seriesName) => seriesName,
            },
          },
          z: {
            formatter: undefined,
            title: "Size: ",
          },
          marker: {
            show: true,
          },

          fixed: {
            enabled: false,
            position: "topRight",
            offsetX: 0,
            offsetY: 0,
          },
        },

        legend: {
          show: true,
          position: "left",
          horizontalAlign: "center",
          width: 300,
          offsetY: 110,
          fontSize: "20px",
          labels: {
            colors: "#ffffff",
          },
          itemMargin: {
            vertical: 10,
          },
        },
        xaxis: {
          type: "numeric",
          labels: {
            rotate: 0,
            style: {
              colors: [
                "#72858a",
                "#72858a",
                "#72858a",
                "#72858a",
                "#72858a",
                "#72858a",
                "#72858a",
              ],
              fontSize: "12px",
              fontFamily: "Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
              fontWeight: 400,
              cssClass: "apexcharts-xaxis-label",
            },
            
          },
        },
        yaxis: {
           labels:{
             style: {
               colors: [
                "#72858a",
                "#72858a",
                "#72858a",
                "#72858a",
                "#72858a",
                "#72858a",
                "#72858a",
              ],
             }
           }
        },

        colors: ["#a4a82c", "#c416b9"],
        tickAmount: "dataPoints",
        grid: {
          show: true,
          borderColor: "#2a2c3d",
          strokeDashArray: 0,

          fill: {
            type: "gradient",
          },
          position: "back",

          xaxis: {
            lines: {
              show: true,
            },
          },
          yaxis: {
            lines: {
              show: true,
            },
          },
          row: {
            colors: undefined,
            opacity: 0.5,
          },
          column: {
            colors: undefined,
            opacity: 0.5,
          },
          padding: {
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 10,
          },
        },
      },
    };
  },

  watch: {
    title(val) {
      console.log("val", val);
    },

    dataset: {
      handler: function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log("newValue-dataset", newValue);
        console.log("oldValue", oldValue);
        if (newValue && newValue["x"]) {
          let series = [
            {
              name: "  Portfolio Pnl",

              data: this.dataset["y_portf"].map((item, index) => {
                return {
                  x: this.dataset["x"][index],
                  y: item.toFixed(2),
                };
              }),
            },
            {
              name: "  Structure Pnl",
              data: this.dataset["y_struct"].map((item, index) => {
                return {
                  x: this.dataset["x"][index],
                  y: item.toFixed(2),
                };
              }),
            },
          ];

          this.series = series;
        }
      },
      deep: true,
      immediate: true,
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$refs.chart.hideSeries("  Portfolio Pnl");
      console.log("this.$refs.chart", this.$refs.chart);
    });
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

Answer (score 1):

В apex можно только юзать или `dark` или `light` чтоб задать кастомное надо обращаться к стилю чекайте доку [tooltip](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/tooltip/)

```
.apexcharts-tooltip {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: orange;
  }
```

[image: Documentation]

Comment: Я получаю вот такую ошибку когда добавляю это в стили
Syntax Error: TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function

Comment: Я понизил версию sas и удалось запустить ваш код, правда он не сработал. Меню все так же белым фоном..

Comment: @yOz если у вас в стилях стоит scoped попробуйте заюзать перед класом 
::v-deep .axexcharts-tooltip{...}

Comment: @yOz есть вариант что это вовсе не tooltip и вам просто надо поменять цвет какого-то блока который есть в компоненте по-этому советую заюзать ::v-deep <клас блока где надо поменять цвет>

Answer (score 0):

```
.apexcharts-menu {
  background-color: #27293d !important;
border: 0px;
}
```